# How to create a destname which includes date and time at installation in Inno Set-up

Tags: inno-setup

I want to use the `[Files]` section to create a new file which has the format:

```
Program Name plus date plus time .fmpur
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance the following way. How to modify a date time pattern, see the [`GetDateTimeString`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getdatetimestring) page:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

#define FileNamePattern SetupSetting("AppName") + " " + GetDateTimeString('dd-mm-yyyy hh-nn-ss', '-', ':') + ".fmpur";

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "{#FileNamePattern}"
```

Comment: @TLama Does this use the date at the time of build or the date that the setup is run?  I need the date that the setup is run.

Comment: @RichC, the function used here is a preprocessor function, so it's a pre-compilation timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to TLama's example using a function to get the filename.

```
[code]
function GetFileName(Dummy: String): String;
begin
    Result := SetupSetting("AppName") + " " + GetDateTimeString('dd-mm-yyyy hh-nn-ss', '-', ':') + ".fmpur";
end;

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "{code:GetFileName}"
```