# Inno Setup setup file name append AppVersion

Tags: inno-setup

How to append `AppVersion` to `setup.exe` file?

In other words, how to make output filename as `sample-setup-1.4.2.0.exe`?

```
[Setup]
AppName= {#GetStringFileInfo("Sample.exe", "ProductName")}
AppVersion= {#GetStringFileInfo("Sample.exe", "FileVersion")}

OutputBaseFilename=setup
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two valuable lessons are;

1. [Lesson 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361199/using-getstringfileinfo-in-setup-section-of-inno-setup): Inline function should be used as `{#FunctionName(...)}`
2. [Lesson 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728572/how-to-create-a-destname-which-includes-date-and-time-at-installation-in-inno-se): variables in `[Setup]` field are called by using `SetupSetting` function.

With above information, we can make `sample-setup-1.0.0.0` as below;

```
OutputBaseFilename=sample-setup-{#SetupSetting("AppVersion")}
```

Likewise, we can append datetime;

```
OutputBaseFilename=sample-setup-{#SetupSetting("AppVersion") + GetDateTimeString('dd-mm-yyyy hh-nn-ss', '-', ':')}
```