# Inno Setup - ass AppVersion to DefaultDirName

Tags: inno-setup

Simple question I hope,

I would like to install my app, into "C:\program files\MyApp v1.0.0.1"

The name is always the same but the last part "v1.0.0.1" will change each release.

I can just hard code the whole folder name, it works, but for sure I will for get to update this line one day.

Can I not "&" the "AppVersion" to the string for "DefaultDirName"

I found this: 
[[Inno Setup setup file name append AppVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378299/inno-setup-setup-file-name-append-appversion][1])

and tried:

```
AppVersion=1.4.0.0
AppPublisher=ABC
AppPublisherURL=""
DefaultDirName={pf}MyApp + ("AppVersion")
```

It comppiles, but when I run it, it gives an error message somthing like ...?!/. etc can not be in the file name...

Any ideas, seems simple, I just don't know how to do it :-(
Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0.1"

[setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName} v{#MyAppVersion}
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks Ross

Comment: But if you do not change `AppId` as well, when upgrading, the new version will go to the same folder as the old version.

Comment: thanks for this comment. My AppId is a GUID, it seems to be ok in creating the next folder (pf/MyApp 1.1, pf/MyApp 1.2) etc, but uninstalling it via Add/Removes programs seems to only have one entry, is there a methods to auto gen a fresh GUID? .